# Ignore_above for text datatype in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

In elasticsearch 5 `string` datatype has been removed as explained nicely in this [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings) post.

`ignore_above` is not supported with `text` datatype. Can someone let me know how does `text` field is then protected against Lucene’s term byte-length limit as explained in the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html), especially the below section

> This option is also useful for protecting against Lucene’s term
>   byte-length limit of 32766 .

Comment: `ignore_above` is for `keyword`s, which by definition have one term only. `text` should be analyzed and split into multiple terms. And there are ways for analyzers to limit the size of a token. The [`standard` analyzer has `max_token_length` option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) while for custom analyzers you can use the [length token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-length-tokenfilter.html).

Comment: Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ignore_above` is for `keyword`s, which by definition have one term only. `text` should be analyzed and split into multiple terms. And there are ways for analyzers to limit the size of a token. The [`standard` analyzer has `max_token_length` option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) while for custom analyzers you can use the [length token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-length-tokenfilter.html).